# How to check if a user has ever ordered a product/list of products

Tags: commerce

Given a list of product IDs, I'm trying to determine if a user has ever purchased any of them.

At the moment my logic consists of loading all the orders related to a user, then looping through the order lines to check individual product IDs:

```
$ordered = FALSE;

$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$product_ids = array();
foreach ($node_wrapper->field_products as $product) {
  $product_ids[] = $product->product_id->value();
}

$orders = commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('uid' => $account->uid, 'status' => 'checkout_checkout'));
foreach ($orders as $order) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $order_line) {
    $product = $order_line->commerce_product;
    if (in_array($product->product_id->value(), $product_ids)) {
      $ordered = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

This feels like a long way round, and that perhaps I'm missing a helper function somewhere in Commerce that would get me this information.

Anyone know if such a function exists, or if there's a more elegant method to get this data?

NB. I know 'checkout_checkout' isn't the right order status for the production code, this is just test code at the moment.

I'm looking for an API solution to this; building up an SQL query would obviously be very easy, but more verbose and error-prone. What I'm looking for is a *more* elegant solution than my existing one (if one exists; it might not).

Comment: Not a solution: I've seen something similar for compatibility warnings, done by exposing commerce tables to views with help of a custom module and then pretty... brave view. Possible, and one query with couple joins, so supposedly faster, but feels so wrong.

Comment: Orders have the uid on them, not line items. So, as far as I know, you'll need to iterate over the orders, then the line items to check the products for the user there. Basically something similar to the approach you've taken. Alternatively, you may be able to craft an SQL query with the appropriate joins for the job.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm already checking the uid against the order (not the line item), have I misunderstood something? Actually, what you've described as an alternative is exactly what I'm already doing; do you have an example of the 'simliar' approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach, using an SQL query

```
$ordered = FALSE;

$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$product_ids = array();
foreach ($node_wrapper->field_products as $product) {
  $product_ids[] = $product->product_id->value();
}

// Query order details for products
// Note this is the line item product reference table
$query = db_select('field_data_commerce_product', 'p');
// Example if you want more fields, but would need to change ->fetchCol()
// $query->fields('o', array('order_id', 'order_number', 'uid', 'mail'));
$query->fields('o', array('uid'));
$query->innerJoin('field_data_commerce_line_items', 'l', 'l.commerce_line_items_line_item_id = p.entity_id');
$query->innerJoin('commerce_order', 'o', 'o.order_id = l.entity_id');
$query->condition('p.commerce_product_product_id', $product_ids, 'IN');
$query->groupBy('o.order_id');
// Fetch array of uids
$result = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

// Check if account->uid in array of order uids
// If so, uid has ordered product.
if(in_array($account->uid, $result)){
  $ordered = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: you should check order status because order can be in state `cart` or `checkout`

Answer (score 0):

In a project I added a hidden field called 'Bought history' to user account, containing a list of products a user has bought, then using Rules module in the event of "completing checkout" I added the product ID to user's bought history.

Now I easily load user data, and check if products are stored in this list or not (Even node ID can be saved rather than Product ID)

Comment: I really want to know if it's a good solution or not, and if it's not, then why is that?